# "Permission denied" error when deleting files although owner of file

Tags: permissions, delete

```
-rw------- 1 sato_y sato_y   19 Aug 15  2018 _complete 
drwx------ 2 sato_y sato_y   68 Aug 15  2018 files
-rw------- 1 sato_y sato_y  673 Aug 15  2018 _invocation 

[sato_y@ircms-icals fork0]$ rm _complete  
rm: cannot remove ‘_complete’: Permission denied
```

I am having an error when trying to delete files in my directories in our storage server. As in the example above, when I tried to remove the file, I got a "permission denied" message. I checked and the file and the directory it is in belongs to me with write permission.

However, when I make a new directory and move the file into that said directory, I was able to delete it as I show below.

```
-rwx------ 1 sato_y sato_y   19 Aug 15  2018 _complete
drwx------ 2 sato_y sato_y   68 Aug 15  2018 files
-rw------- 1 sato_y sato_y  673 Aug 15  2018 _invocation

[sato_y@ircms-icals fork0]$ mkdir delete
[sato_y@ircms-icals fork0]$ mv _complete ./delete/
[sato_y@ircms-icals fork0]$ ll

total 448
drwx------ 3 sato_y sato_y  102 Mar  4  2019 delete
drwx------ 2 sato_y sato_y   68 Aug 15  2018 files
-rw------- 1 sato_y sato_y  673 Aug 15  2018 _invocation

[sato_y@ircms-icals fork0]$ rm -rf delete
[sato_y@ircms-icals fork0]$ ll
total 384
drwx------ 2 sato_y sato_y   68 Aug 15  2018 files
-rw------- 1 sato_y sato_y  673 Aug 15  2018 _invocation
```

Whenever I try to delete a directory, there will be some leftover files which I was unable to delete and I had to resort to this step (making new directory, transfer the said file into it and delete the new directory) to completely remove everything.

Does anyone faced a similar problem before?

Comment: This makes no sense. The `mv` effectively deletes the file from the current directory, just like `rm` would do.

Comment: @kingmilo But even if I delete the current directory containing these files with rm -rf, it still gives me a permission denied error. Only after I make a new directory and move the file into it, only I was able to delete it. 

I am forcing delete the directory because I don't need the files in it anymore. However, if you have any safer method to delete stuff, please inform me.

Comment: Ahh apologies guys, I didn’t look closely enough and thought _complete was a directory, my bad, I’m on my phone. I’ll update comments once on laptop ;)

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, that's the thing! I have the permission to perform actions in the directory, but some files are stubborn in that they refused to be deleted. I need to perform as I mentioned here to be able to delete them.

Comment: @T.Ben Is this a shared type folder? Could you show us the permissions of the directory you’re currently working in?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x  3 sato_y sato_y  102 Mar  4 18:08 del`

No, this is a personal folder. The folder is named "del" and permission is as shown.

Comment: @T.Ben thanks. What file system are you using and what does your /etc/fstab look like? Can you show us the output of `df` and then the output of `id` so we can see what is mounted with what permissions and what groups etc your user belongs to :)

Comment: `# /etc/fstab
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
UUID=3524494b-2cdc-4bcd-b180-3ebaf71b4585 /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=124cbea3-8525-40a4-b14a-1a5aa6ed12cf /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=d474898f-4069-4706-981a-9ffe78c8aa36 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
UUID=a2fefa21-ee02-47cf-b156-b681a5814cf5 /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
10.1.1.100:/Volumes/G-Speed               /G-Speed                nfs     tcp,vers=3,defaults,_netdev 0 0`

Comment: The files in reference are in the /G-Speed/ folder which is our storage server.
Output of `id` is
`uid=1113(sato_y) gid=1113(sato_y) groups=1113(sato_y)`
Output of `df` is in the next 2 comments.

Comment: `Filesystem                    1K-blocks        Used  Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3                     465994436   455000780   10993656  98% /
devtmpfs                      264022356           0  264022356   0% /dev
tmpfs                         264041404           0  264041404   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         264041404      952488  263088916   1% /run
tmpfs                         264041404           0  264041404   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                       1038336      258212     780124  25% /boot`

Comment: `/dev/sdb1                    9762775040  7375348308 2387426732  76% /home
10.1.1.100:/Volumes/G-Speed 41022099392 37119705152 3902394240  91% /G-Speed
192.168.1.3:/data            9762775040  1815965696 7946809344  19% /data
tmpfs                          52808284           0   52808284   0% /run/user/519
tmpfs                          52808284          16   52808268   1% /run/user/1113`